# Android: Custom AutoCompleteTextView shows last item after it has been selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, custom-controls, autocompletetextview

I've implemented a custom auto complete text view to allow users to select tags; when an item is chosen, it correctly calls the listener to set the selected text in the view and color that corresponds with it. The problem i'm having is that the selected item pops instantly back up as one of the choices; I want the item to go away (and could probably do it by keeping track of the pressed item, but is there a cleaner way to do this or something that i'm missing?

Filter:

```
    protected class TagFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if(resultTags == null){
            resultTags = new LinkedList<Tag>();
        }
        else {
            resultTags.clear();
        }
        if (constraint != null) {
            String tagString = constraint.toString();
            for (Tag tag : globalTags) {
                if (tag.getText().startsWith(tagString)) {
                    resultTags.add(tag);
                }

            }
            if(resultTags.size() > 1) Collections.sort(resultTags);
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            results.values = resultTags;
            results.count = resultTags.size();
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        tagAdapter.clear();
        if (results.count > 0) {
            for(Tag tagResult : (List<Tag>)results.values){
                tagAdapter.add(tagResult);
            }
            tagAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            tagAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Tag Adapter Code:

```
    protected class TagAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tag> implements Filterable {
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(tf == null){
            tf = new TagFilter();
        }
        return tf;
    }
    public TagAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(CreateActivity.this);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        text.setTextSize(20);
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        //TODO holder here
        Tag tag = getItem(position);
        text.setText("     " + tag.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        ((Spannable)text.getText()).setSpan(
                new BackgroundColorSpan(tag.getColor()), 
                0, 
                4, 
                0);
        return text;
    }       
}
```

AutoCompleteTextView Listener:

```
    tagText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Tag selectedTag = resultTags.get((int) arg3);

            selectedColor = selectedTag.getColor();
            tagText.setText(selectedTag.getText());
            tagText.dismissDropDown();
        }


    });
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I ended up setting a "clicked" flag to true in the onClick listener and then when the text has been set and the autocomplete tries to filter it again, I just return no results if the flag is set and set the flag to false so normal filtering resumes until a choice is again made. I bet there's a built-in way to do this though, anyone know?